# What does java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method fetchProvidersForEmail(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; mean?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a chat app in android studio using the tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397

As far as I know I have done exactly what he said but my app crashes after I put in the email.

I checked the logcat but couldn't find anything helpful.

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 111;
    private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            // Start sign in/sign up activity
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(), SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            // User is already signed in. Therefore, display
            // a welcome Toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Load chat room contents
            displayChatMessages();
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText input = findViewById(R.id.input);

                // Read the input field and push a new instance
                // of ChatMessage to the Firebase database
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(), FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName()));

                // Clear the input
                input.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully signed in. Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                displayChatMessages();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Close the app
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_sign_out) {
            AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have been signed out.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            // Close activity
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void displayChatMessages() {
        ListView listOfMessages = findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class, R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                // Get references to the views of message.xml
                TextView messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                TextView messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                // Set their text
                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

                // Format the date before showing it
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };

        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

***ChatMessage.java***

```
public class ChatMessage {

    private String messageText;
    private String messageUser;
    private long messageTime;

    public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
        this.messageUser = messageUser;

        // Initialize to current time
        messageTime = new Date().getTime();
    }

    public ChatMessage(){

    }

    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    public String getMessageUser() {
        return messageUser;
    }

    public void setMessageUser(String messageUser) {
        this.messageUser = messageUser;
    }

    public long getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }

    public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
    }
}
```

***Logcat***

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.metalDent.mychatapp, PID: 27237
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method fetchProvidersForEmail(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth' appears in /data/app/com.metalDent.mychatapp-RmMfp5EHXBs_NAwFfRcLJw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.CheckEmailFragment.checkAccountExists(CheckEmailFragment.java:183)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.CheckEmailFragment.validateAndProceed(CheckEmailFragment.java:174)
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.ui.email.CheckEmailFragment.onClick(CheckEmailFragment.java:262)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: In the meanwhile, at which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo, I'm not getting any error. The app is running but crashing after I enter the email. 
That is the logcat.

Answer (score 2):

I`ve been solved this problem by adding to gradle dependencies:

```
   dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
   ...
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your build.gradle file add the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:**17.0.0**'
```

Because the **Authentication version is 17.0.0**

Hope you will find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchProvidersForEmail` has been obsoleted. You should use [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)) instead.